# What is the name/background of this function, $ \phi (x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T Ax - x^T b $?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

For a homework problem we are asked to work with the equation

$$ \phi (x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T Ax - x^T b $$

and prove something about its minimum given a symmetric positive definite matrix. We worked through a proof in class but there are a few parts I am unsure of and I am trying to research them. Though, I am not sure how to search on it because I am not sure of the name of this equation.

I know that it is related to the Arnoldi iteration and GMRES but searching on those doesn't turn up much, if anything, related to this function.

**What is the name of this function? Where does it come from?**

Comment: It's a [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form) (see [definite quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_quadratic_form))

Comment: You can also try "completing the square."  For intuition, consider the scalar case when you have an expression $(1/2)ax^2 - xb$, can you find a minimum by completing the square?

Comment: Assuming that $A$ is symmetric, $\phi$ is the quadratic function whose gradient vanishes on the solution set of the linear system $A x = b$.